# Then the rest of the values need to set ascending order

Tags: java, arrays

suppose, I have 6 instance variable and an array of 6  values. Now I want to set the 1st highest value to selected variable and 2nd to another variable. Then the rest of the values need to set ascending order. How can I do that ?

Comment: could you provide an example? The way it is, it's not clear to me what exactly you'd like to achieve, and which part of it is posing a problem. Do you know how to sort an array?

Answer (score 0):

Put the items 3-x into an `ArrayList` (lets call it restList), then call `restList.sort(comparator)` on it.

If you're using Java 8+, you can write `restList.sort((p,q)->p.getName().compareTo(q.getName()))` or whatever attibutes your Items have, or you wanna sort by.

Now create another List (finalList), add the first two items, then loop over restList and add those items to finalList.

```
finalList.add(item1);
finalList.add(item1);
for (Item i : restList) {
    finalList.add(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking for a way to create a list of values having the first 2 values in descending order and the next 4 values in ascending order, you can follow this example.

Note that, this example uses `List.of()` method from Java 9 and `Stream` from Java 8.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    final DataHolder data = new DataHolder();

    final List<Integer> availableList = List.of(data.var1, data.var2, data.var3, data.var4, data.var5, data.var6);

    final List<Integer> expectedList = 
            Stream.concat(
                    availableList.stream()
                    .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                    .limit(2),
                    availableList.stream()
                    .sorted()
                    .limit(4))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(expectedList);
    }
```

DataHolder class:

```
public class DataHolder {

    public int var1 = 25;
    public int var2 = 42;
    public int var3 = 52;
    public int var4 = 27;
    public int var5 = 19;
    public int var6 = 56;

}
```

I have taken few random values as variable values.